# nordyne hvac furnace will not fire up, tries 2-3 times, the grey resistors get real hot

Tags: electrical, hvac, heating, cooling

nordyne furnace kept giving me communication code, replaced thermostat, ran fine for a week. get pressure switch codes so i replaced them. now it starts cycle and wont fire, if i leave the unit off for a while (1/2 hr or more) it will fire up . but starts to act up  after reaching temp. the grey resistors on the board get real hot too.blew out the drain tubes too. still gives me pressure switch codes

Comment: complete sentence. overrated. communication minimal.

Comment: What model is your furnace?

Comment: Drain tubes? Meh, w/e. You need a new board. But make sure you're getting the proper voltage from the transformer, which is like [34v while unloaded](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/215343/35v-reading-on-24v-transformer).

Comment: its a nordyne gibson 80+ 90+ 2 stage fixed speed up flow furnace. Had service guys here  and replaced the flame sensor and gas valve . ran fine now back to the same thing this morning ! they're thinking board too!